# Android Support package not present in SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk

There is no android support package in my SDK manager, as shown:

[image]

And whenever I try to create an android application project I am presented with this screen at the end:

[image]

If I click install/upgrade this appears:

[image]

And it installs and everything, but nothing happens and it stays on the same screen as before. Clicking `check again` doesn't do anything either.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some weird reason android-sdk decided to install everything in `/extras/compatibility` instead of `/extras/support` which eclipse recognises, so I renamed `/extras/compatibility` to
`/extras/support` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Find your SDK directory, navigate to /extras/android/, in this folder you will see a folder named "compatibility", rename this folder to "support". Re-open Eclipse, create new Android Application Project, the process will complete without this problem occurring again!