# GCM Android Library not Found in the sdk Manager of android studio version 1.5

Tags: android

[image: Screen shot of sdk mamager]

Screen shot of sdk manager....

I m trying to implement a push notification through GCM solution for android.
But there is no library for GCM in sdk manager of android studio 1.5 version . It is quite strange to me because i have switched from android studio 1.2 to android studio 1.5. Is there any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21546273

Comment: The problem is that there is no extra field in sdk manager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11244161,http://stackoverflow.com/a/18694991

Comment: Is two links there, try one by one

Comment: are you have install google play service in sdk android?

Comment: ya i have install google play service

Answer (score 0):

this gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```